# Using framer motion with Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, css-animations, framer-motion

So I was using framer motion with Typescript and I was wondering if there is a way to make your variants typesafe so that you can get nice autocomplete and make fewer mistakes. I was also using the custom prop for custom data and would like to make that typesafe. here is an example snippet:

```
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

export default function App() {
  const variants = {
    initial: (x: number) => {
      return {
        x: x
      };
    },
    final: {
      x: 0,
      transition: {
        duration: 0.8
      }
    }
  };
  return (
    <motion.div
      className="App"
      variants={variants}
      custom={100}
      initial="initial"
      animate="final"
    >
      <h1>Framer Motion</h1>
      <h2>Testing with typescript</h2>
    </motion.div>
  );
}
```

so what I want is that after defining my variants when I use them in my `motion.div` it should provide autocompletion that the possible values for `initial` prop are "initial" and "final" and also provide type safety with the custom value. Right now I have defined that the value of x should be a number but in the custom prop even if given an array or object it does not complain. I have tried to import Variants from framer motion and tried to use it like this `const variants: Variants{}` but it doesn't seem to work. Please help me if I am doing this in the correct way or not.

Answer (score 0):

With the retyping the initial prop you can create your custom motion div component which will extend the base type with yours

https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-elion-xzt7g3

```
interface CustomMotionDivProps extends HTMLMotionProps<"div"> {
  initial: "initial" | "final";
  // any other thing
}

export default class CustomMotionDiv extends Component<CustomMotionDivProps> {
  render() {
    return <motion.div {...this.props}>{this.props.children}</motion.div>;
  }
}
```

The other problem you have with the `variants` I do not understand. If you want prop `variants` of the motion.div to allow exact type, you can define it next to the `initial` in the CustomMotionDiv.